# what is the best way to bypass the captcha in my python code?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, recaptcha

How can I bypass the captcha in my python code? Every time I am making a request it is asking me to complete the puzzle below.  What is the best way to bypass the captcha? Is there a library I can use that will complete the puzzle automatically for me when it appears?

[image]

here is my code

```
def get_data():
    NAME = []
    TURNOVER = []
    SIZE = []
    EMPLOYEES = []
    FULL_ADDRESS = []
    POST_TOWN = []
    POST_CODE = []
    SIC_CODE = []
    DIRECTORS = []
    TELEPHONE = []
    EMAIL = []
    WEBSITE = []

    df = pd.read_csv('./Links.csv')
    R_LINKS = df['LINKS'].to_list()

    for links in R_LINKS:
        print(links)

        driver = uc.Chrome()

        try:
            driver.get(links)
            time.sleep(5)
            content = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
            driver.quit()
            body = soup.body
            company_name = body.find_all(
                'h1', {'itemprop': 'name'})[0].getText()
            NAME.append(company_name.strip())

            kompass_id = body.find_all('tr', {'class': 'trKid'})[
                0].find('td').getText()
            number = body.find_all('input', {
                                   'id': f'freePhone-contactCompanyForCompany-{kompass_id}'})[0].get('value')
            TELEPHONE.append(number)

            website = body.find_all('a', {'id': 'webSite_presentation_0'})[
                0].getText()
            WEBSITE.append(website)

            employees = soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile('Employees'))[
                0].getText()
            EMPLOYEES.append(employees)
            address = body.find_all('p', {'class': 'blockAddress'})[
                0].getText().split()

            postcode = address[len(address) - 2] + ' ' + \
                address[len(address) - 1]
            POST_CODE.append(postcode)

            fulladdress = []
            for a in body.find_all('p', {'class': 'blockAddress'}):
                address = a.getText()
                fulladdress.append(address.strip())
            addressses = ' '.join(fulladdress).split()
            FULL_ADDRESS.append(' '.join(addressses))

            type = soup.find('th', text=re.compile('SIC07'))
            SIC_CODE.append(type.parent.findNext('td').contents[0].strip())

            directors = []
            for d in body.find_all('p', {'class': 'executiveName'}):
                director = d.getText()
                directors.append(director.strip())
            DIRECTORS.append(' '.join(directors))
        except:
            pass

    print('POST_CODE', POST_CODE)

    new_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'POST_CODE': POST_CODE,
        'FULL_ADDRESS': FULL_ADDRESS,
        'SIC_CODE': SIC_CODE,
        'DIRECTORS': DIRECTORS,
        'NAME': NAME,
        'POST_CODE': POST_CODE,
        'TELEPHONE': TELEPHONE,
        'WEBSITE': WEBSITE
    })
    new_df.to_csv('data.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

I am passing in these URL links

```
https://gb.kompass.com/c/unisto-ltd/gb82592280/
https://gb.kompass.com/c/spotler/gb25036694/
https://gb.kompass.com/c/parts-plus/gb55346048/
```

Answer (score 1):

Bypassing Captcha is difficult because they are designed to **not** be bypassed by bots. A few points and things you can try:

- Selenium specifically and other automation tools have certain user agents and other identifiers which indicate that it's automated. So maybe have a play around with things like that
- Anti bot tools look at browsing behaviours and patterns so try to slow it and randomize it eg. random sleep instead of 5
- You may be able to use Selenium or some kind of macro to simulate swiping the screen
- You could in principle use an OCR library to solve the challenges however this will most likely be very difficult and time consuming
- There are APIs available that will solve Captcha codes for you however they are paid services
- Another trick is to look at the website and try to find if there are any alternative routes to get the information. For example: is there a public API you can use to bypass it? Is there a mobile version of the website? Sometimes mobile versions have less aggressive Captcha enforcement